# Upload image, Internal Server Error

Tags: php

I want to upload a simple image to the server in iPage, but it gives to me the Internar Server error and I have no idea what is happening.
The php.ini is all right, I don't touch anything. This is some code

```
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 20M
```

And this is my basic php file:

```
<?php

$path = 'images/example.jpg';
$encoded_string = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';
$decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);
    $file = fopen($path, 'wb');
console_log( $decoded_string);
$is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
fclose($file);
?>
```

The folder permissions are 755 and the scripts permission are 644.
I can't acced to the log error console.

The script is writing the image, hi.jpg in the correct folder, but it has 0 bytes, and the error is:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

I have no idea why is this happening

Comment: Is folder permission `755` or `775`?

Comment: You can even try with [error_get_last](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php)

Comment: Some hosting services (especially Microsoft hostings) don't allow you to upload files in any other folder than `/public/`, even when having permissions 755. Can you check if it's the case?

Comment: Yes, the folder has the correct permission, and even in /public/ it does not work.

Comment: Open error logs and read'em.

Comment: As I have said: I can't acced to the log error console.

Comment: The first step to know whats happening is read the logs. Without them you're blind. May be just a missing ; or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution.
I thought the problem was on the server or in the permissions, but I was wrong.

What is incorrect is the PHP script.

The function base64_decode can't decode becouse the explode was missing.

```
list($type, $encoded_string) = explode(';', $encoded_string);
list(, $encoded_string) = explode(',', $encoded_string);
```

Before the decode function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the `file_uploads` setting in php.ini , make sure it's `on` . You can even use

```
ini_set("file_uploads","On");
```

Comment: Yes, it is enabled.